# Simple Injector WPF invalid uri

Tags: wpf, simple-injector, mahapps.metro

I am getting a error when trying to verify container.

> The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type
>   SettingModel failed. The registered delegate for type SettingModel
>   threw an exception. Invalid URI: Invalid port specified.

It seems to be caused by `ThemeManager` which belongs to mahapps.metro dll I can't seem to get it to play nicely with Simple Injector.

```
public SettingModel()
{
    ThemeColor = ThemeManager.AppThemes.Select(t => t.Name).ToList();
    AccentColor = ThemeManager.Accents.Select(a => a.Name).ToList();

    var currentSetting = ThemeManager.DetectAppStyle(Application.Current);
    CurrentTheme = currentSetting.Item1.Name;
    CurrentAccent = currentSetting.Item2.Name;
}
```

I slowly remove stuff and it got to the point where every where I used theme manager it was breaking. So I start taking out pieces until I got to the point where I kept getting xamlparseexception when I compile which is strange because my code complied before I put in the simple injector.

I followed the tutorial for WPF integration unless that is out dated. I really wanted to try simple injector but it isn't integrating nicely.

Update: Full exception

```
    System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
      HResult=-2146233079
      Message=The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type MainWindow failed. The registered delegate for type MainWindow threw an exception. Invalid URI: Invalid port specified.
      Source=SimpleInjector
      StackTrace:
           at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.VerifyInstanceCreation()
           at SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyInstanceCreation(InstanceProducer[] producersToVerify)
           at SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyThatAllRootObjectsCanBeCreated()
           at SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyInternal()
           at SimpleInjector.Container.Verify(VerificationOption option)
           at SimpleInjector.Container.Verify()
           at Program.Bootstrap() in c:\Users\Work\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AzurePeek\AzurePeek\Program.cs:line 35
           at Program.Main() in c:\Users\Work\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AzurePeek\AzurePeek\Program.cs:line 14
           at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
           at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
           at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
           at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
           at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
           at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
           at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
           at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
      InnerException: SimpleInjector.ActivationException
           HResult=-2146233088
           Message=The registered delegate for type MainWindow threw an exception. Invalid URI: Invalid port specified.
           Source=SimpleInjector
           StackTrace:
                at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()
                at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.VerifyInstanceCreation()
           InnerException: System.UriFormatException
                HResult=-2146233033
                Message=Invalid URI: Invalid port specified.
                Source=System
                StackTrace:
                     at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
                     at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
                     at MahApps.Metro.ThemeManager.get_AppThemes()
                     at AzurePeek.M

odel.SettingModel..ctor() in c:\Users\Work\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AzurePeek\AzurePeek\Model\SettingModel.cs:line 24
                 at lambda_method(Closure )
                 at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()
            InnerException:
```

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**

After a discussion with @punker76, who is one of the colaborators of the MahApps.Metro library, we concluded that this exception happens because you are running that code out of the scope of a WPF application. Most likely because you are testing your configuration inside a unit test.

There are two things you can do here. Either you need to fool your test suite to think it runs as a WPF application or you will have to move the code that depends on `MyApps` out of the `SettingModel`'s constructor.

As discussed with @punker76, when starting a WPF application, a call to `new FrameworkElement()` somehow ensures that the internal `UriParser` is able to parse `pack://` uris (talk about weird hidden ugly scary dependencies).

The other option, which is my preference, is to make [constructor's simple and resilient to failure](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/). This means that any code that is not related to building up the object graph should be moved out of the constructor and should be done at runtime.

There are a lot of ways to do this, but a simple way to do this is by postponing the initialization of the properties of the `SettingsModel` or postponing the creation of `SettingsModel` itself, since it doesn't look like a service that should be maintained by your DI container at all.

Postponing the creation of `SettingsModel` is easy by introducing an abstraction that allows access to the settings at runtime:

```
public interface ISettingsProvider {
    SettingsModel CurrentSettings { get; }
}
```

With the following implementation:

```
public class SettingsProvider : ISettingsProvider {
    private readonly Lazy<SettingsModel> model = new Lazy<SettingsModel>(
        () => new SettingsModel());

    public SettingsModel CurrentSettings {
        get { return this.model.Value; }
    }
}
```

This can be registered as follows:

```
container.RegisterSingle<ISettingsProvider>(new SettingsProvider());
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

The problem is unlikely to be caused by Simple Injector. There isn't anything special about Simple Injector's `Verify()` method. If you replace the call to `Verify()` with `new SettingModel();`, you will most likely see the same exception.

As a matter of fact, if you look at [the source code](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/5509b1cc1babf7cda2f4b3fa41c805f40e51b9ff/MahApps.Metro/ThemeManager.cs) of the `MahApps.Metro.ThemeManager.AppThemes` property, you'll see the following code:

```cs
var themes = new[] { "BaseLight", "BaseDark" };

_appThemes = new List<AppTheme>(themes.Length);

foreach (var color in themes)
{
    var appTheme = new AppTheme(color, new Uri(string.Format("pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/{0}.xaml", color)));

    _appThemes.Add(appTheme);
}

return _appThemes;
```

If you look at the url that is supplied to the `Uri` constructor, you can understand why it throws an "Invalid URI: Invalid port specified" exception. If you run the following code in a console application, you will get the same error:

```cs
new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml");
```

So I have to conclude that there is a bug in the `MahApps.Metro.ThemeManager.AppThemes` property that is causing this. I'm wondering how you actually managed to get this working before, because I don't see a way to work around that bug. Did you happen to upgrade to a newer version of MahApps.Metro at the same time as you introduced Simple Injector?

Comment: Interesting at the start of my application I used the latest one from nuget. Everything seem to work just fine when I installed and used it through out my application. . . .
Ironically if I just completely rip out the setting model I start getting errors for resources that use mahapps.metro  . . . hmm

Comment: @ThaoNguyen: It seems to me that this mahapps.metro might need some additional development.

Comment: @Steven why do you think there is a bug with the URI?

Comment: @punker76: There's no bug in the `Uri` class, but the .NET `Uri` class simply does not accept the port `pack://`, so there is clearly a bug inside the `AppThemes` property of MahApps.Metro.

Comment: @Steven mh, this is new to me, that Uri doesn't accept pack:// -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @punker76 I'm sorry, I'm not making this up. I'm running .NET 4.5 and the Uri class throws the exception as described by the OP. Please test it yourself.

Comment: @Steven I have not worked yet with SimpleInjector, but in my opinion it's more a problem with it, cause in all normal cases Uri works correct.

Comment: @punker76: I'm unsure why you would say that. As I described in my answer, if you run the `new Uri("pack://...)` line in an *empty* .NET 4.5 console application (so *no* Simple Injector Involved) it just throws that 'Invalid URI' exception. So this is clearly not related to Simple Injector *at all*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80129/discussion-between-punker76-and-steven).

Comment: Updated the question after discussion with @punker76.